# Python program crashes when I assign tags to a Gtk.TextView

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I am trying to write a program that will take data from a Gtk.TextView and assign tags for it. Basically a markdown formatter. But whenever I add a * * set for itallics the entire program crashes.

This is the code I had. It's not the best looking code because I was experimenting with the idea.

```
# Imports
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class MarkdownFormatter:
    def __init__(self, textview):
        self.textview = textview
        self.text_buffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        self.text_buffer.connect('insert-text', self.on_key_insert)
        self.tag_bold = self.text_buffer.create_tag('bold',weight=Pango.Weight.BOLD)
        self.tag_italic = self.text_buffer.create_tag('italic',style=Pango.Style.ITALIC, )
        self.tag_underline = self.text_buffer.create_tag('underline',underline=Pango.Underline.SINGLE)
        self.bold= False
        self.italic = False
        self.italic_start_iter = Gtk.TextIter()
        self.italic_end_iter = Gtk.TextIter()
        self.underline = False
        
    def on_key_insert(self, buffer, inter, text, iteg):
        end= self.text_buffer.get_end_iter()
        start= self.text_buffer.get_start_iter()
        all_text = self.text_buffer.get_text(end, start, True)
        self.text_buffer.remove_all_tags(start, end)
        count = 0
        self.italic =  False
        for d in all_text:
            count+= 1
            if '*' in d:
                if self.italic == False:
                    self.italic = True
                    self.italic_start_iter.set_offset(count)
                elif self.italic:
                    self.italic = False
                    self.italic_end_iter.set_offset(count)
                    self.text_buffer.apply_tag(self.tag_italic, self.italic_start_iter, self.italic_end_iter)

text = '''
*I is good.*
she is smart.
"Hi" he said.

'''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    def quit(*args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    window = Gtk.Window.new(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_title('Markdown formatter')
    view = Gtk.TextView()
    view.get_buffer().set_text(text)

    formater = MarkdownFormatter(view)

    window.set_default_size(600, 400)
    window.add(view)
    window.show_all()
    window.connect('delete-event', quit)
    Gtk.main()
```

Run the program and then when you try to type anything it'll crash (It only tries to format the text when you type.

Comment: It seems all three of the lines `self.italic_start_iter.set_offset(count)`, `self.italic_end_iter.set_offset(count)`, and `self.text_buffer.apply_tag(self.tag_italic, self.italic_start_iter, self.italic_end_iter)` are causing this problem. When I comment out two of them and leave the third, it still crashes, no matter which one I leave uncommented.

So my _guess_ would be that it has something to do with the fact that they're being called in a callback, but I could be wrong...

Comment: I tried set the start iter and end iter to the start and end of the text (using start and end) It still crashed. What's weirder is it doesn't even give an error. Period. Which is the strange bit. Could it be a bug with gtk?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I have no idea why so if someone can figure out why I'd be very happy.

Basically if you replace the  `set_offset`(s) with a `itername = buffer.get_iter_at_offset(count)` It will run fine.

My only guess is that it's something to do with reusing buffers or there's an issue with set_offset.